# Angular 5 - ngClass - Not able to add multiple classes

Tags: html, typescript, angular5

Started to learn Angular 5 and am stuck with `ngClass` directive. I am trying to apply multiple classes based on a condition, but somehow only 1/2 classes are being applied.

**mainnav.component.html**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top"
    [ngClass]="{
    'navbar-dark bg-dark' : themeColor === 'dark',
    'navbar-dark bg-primary' : themeColor === 'blue',
    'navbar-light bg-light' : themeColor === 'light'
    }">
...
...
<li class="nav-item">
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
    <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search" (keyup)="onButtonClicked($event)">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" [disabled]="!allowSearch" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
</li>
<li class="nav-item dropdown" (mouseover)="openDropDown($event)">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Change Theme
    </a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" (click)="enableDarkTheme()">Dark</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" (click)="enableLightTheme()">Light</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" (click)="enableBlueTheme()">Blue</a>
    </div>
</li>
```

**mainnav.component.ts**

```
themeColor: string = 'dark';
enableDarkTheme() {
    this.themeColor = 'dark';
  }

  enableLightTheme() {
    this.themeColor = 'light';
  }

  enableBlueTheme() {
    this.themeColor = 'blue';
  }
```

The conditions seems to be working fine, but I am not sure why one class is not added as seen in screenshot below,

[image]

Does anyone know if my usage of `ngClass` is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [previous bug report](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/17274) in the Angular GitHub repo on this very topic.

The reason is because `[ngClass]` will add classes for the ones that resolve to `true` and remove classes for those that resolve to `false`. You are using the same class in multiple cases which creates the problem.

Comment: Interesting! I also missed the point of `ngClass` that it removes classes if the condition is `false`. Thanks for the link :) For sake of completeness, this is my new code - `[ngClass]="{
    'navbar-dark' : themeColor === 'dark' || themeColor === 'blue',
    'bg-dark' : themeColor === 'dark',
    'bg-primary' : themeColor === 'blue',
    'navbar-light bg-light' : themeColor === 'light'
  }`